# Calculating Closed form of Basel type problem.

Tags: transcendental-numbers, constants

I want to find the sum of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\phi(n)}}$.

where $\phi$ is Euler's totient.

So for example $\frac{1}{1^1} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{3^2} +\frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{5^4} + \frac{1}{6^2}$ etc...

I also want to find the sum of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\lambda(n)}}$.

where $\lambda(n)$ is Carmichael's Lambda Function

I don't have a nice calculator so I can't approximate the values properly, but ideally I want to find a closed form.

I think it would end up being something like $\frac{1}{4} + y\frac{\pi^x}{k}$ where $y,x$and $k$ are different real numbers. The $\frac{1}{4}$ is by splitting the $\frac{1}{2}$ into $2 \times \frac{1}{2^2}$ where one gets used in the series and the other goes outside.

The reason I believe there is a closed form is because all the even Basel problems have closed answers $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2x}}$ and the totient and lambda functions also produce even numbers.

Comment: I see no reason to expect closed forms.  The first sum is approximately 1.703391799, the second 1.727448185.

Comment: It should have pi in the numerator right?

Comment: Robert, can I get some more decimal places so I can put it into wolfram alpha to see if it can find a closed form.

Comment: If there's no closed form, there's no numerator that $\pi$ should be in.

Comment: We have $\phi(n) \ge 6$ for $n \ge 13$, so the partial sum$\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-\phi(n)}$ should be accurate to within $1/(5 N^5)$.  $N = 7500$ should suffice for about $20$ digits of accuracy.  So: $1.7033917992815305453$.

Comment: The decimal expansion of the first sum is here: [A239725](http://oeis.org/A239725).